# Create new git project: Is not valid HTTP Git repository

Tags: gitlab

I try create new git projects with files from the existing project: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your-token>" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
        "name": "new_project", "description": "New Project", "path": "new_project",
        "import_url": "https://user:token@gitlab.com/<path>.git",
        "namespace_id": "42", "initialize_with_readme": "false"}' \
     --url 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/'
```

But I got the error:

```
{"message":"https://user:token@gitlab.com/<path>.git is not a valid HTTP Git repository"}
```

I was found the issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/360266 with same error, but I set "initialize_with_readme": "false"

Gitlab version is 14.9.2

Also I tried use a broken url as import_url and got this error too

Comment: Are you literally setting the `import_url` to `https://gitlab.com/<path>.git`? That's not a valid existing Git repository.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you mentioned used:

```
https://user:token@gitlab.example.com/templates/someproject.git
        ^^^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            |                         |- replace with your project/repo name
            |
            |- needed if the import project is private
               and need authentication to be accessed
```

That type of URL might work better in your case.

---

It this is somehow not supported, as in [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cant-import-git-project-is-not-a-valid-http-git-repository/68422/5) (Apr. 2022) mentioned by the OP, the workaround is:

> In any case we just worked around it by creating a blank project in the new GitLab, then pulling and pushing the project from the old one and into the new one.

Comment: Tired it, but it's not work=((((

Comment: @Vetedde Does `git ls-remote https://user:token@gitlab.com/<path>.git` works (ie returns anything?)

Comment: yes, it returns Head and master

Comment: @Vetedde So you can access it. Can you try `https://gitlab.com/<path>.git`, without authentication in the URL?

Comment: I tried it too and got this error again=(

Comment: @Vetedde For testing, would `gitlab.com/<path>.git` or `<path>.git` be acceptable here?

Comment: no, I can't. But I found new issue https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cant-import-git-project-is-not-a-valid-http-git-repository/68422 and guys couldn't solve it too=(

Comment: @Vetedde OK, that is unfortunate. I have edited the answer to reference this thread, and  inlcude its workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This coding works well.

`gitLabApi.getProjectApi().createProject(pro,"https://username:password@host/group/front-template.git");`

[image]

Comment: The account 'username:password' need has permission of ‘front-template’